# Block the "food" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

While we are not a site for all things food, the opposite is true: if a question isn't about food, it's quite certainly not within our scope.

That's why I was surprised to discover today that we have a [food](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) tag. For me, this is a quintessential example of a useless tag, since it has zero discrimination ability.

I already cleaned it up from existing questions. To prevent it from being recreated, I'm suggesting that we ask the employees to blacklist the tag for our site.

Comment: brb dividing the entire site into "food" questions and "cooking" questions :) but yeah this is a no-brainer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [food](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) tag has been blocked. Please let us know if you see any issues or need to make any tweaks.